# Are LocalUser.LastLogon updated with IIS FTP logins?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of the latest users that connected to the IIS FTP server. I have an FTP group on my Windows 2008 R2 Server.

```perl
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group FTP | Select-Object LastLogon
```

I know that I can check recent FTP logins with the FTP log file, but each LocalUser has a LastLogon property. Is this property updated when someone uses its account to connect to the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the test myself. It is indeed the case.

However, this technique doesn't allow us to know whether the last logon was a Windows login or an FTP login (to my current knowledge). But that's not really important for my use case anyways.